# Passing an IEnumerable to a view to generate a form and then passing form data back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project for my office. The end result I'm looking for is that a boilerplate letter is pulled from a database, the sections that need specific input are extracted, a form is generated from those sections, the form then returns user data, and the letter is rebuilt with the user data integrated into the text of the letter.

for example, the string pulled from the database would look like this

```
Claim #: |string^clmNum^Claim Number: | - Ref#: |string^RefNum^Reference Number: |
```

and would end up like the following after it was rebuilt with user data:

```
Claim #: 123456 - Ref#: 789012
```

This is what I have working so far...

The sections between the | are pulled out, split, and loaded into an IEnumerable

My foo model is:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string InputType {get; set;}
   public string InputName {get; set;}
   public string InputLabel {get; set;}
}
```

I pass the IEnumerable to the view with a ViewModel

```
public class FormBuildViewModel
{

   public IEnumerable<Foo> FooProperty {get; set;}

}
```

I then display the input items dynamically with the following Razor markup on my view.

```
<form>
@{ var e = Model.FooProperty.ToList();


    foreach (var subItem in e)
    {
       <div class="FormGroup-items">
         <label>@subItem.InputLabel</label>
         <input name="@subItem.ObjName" type="text" />
       </div>
    }
 }
<..// form button stuff //..>
</form>
```

Which creates the following HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="FormGroup-items">
        <label>Claim Number: </label>
        <input name="clmNum" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="FormGroup-items">
        <label>Reference Number: </label>
        <input name="RefNum" type="text" />
    </div>

    <..// button stuff //..>
</form>
```

I have everything working up to this point.  I need to take the data entered on the dynamically created form and get it back to the controller in a manner that I can index to rebuild the string.

I've tried using the @html.beginform similar to this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for(int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsActive, new { @value = Model[i].Id })
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

but to use @Html.BeginForm you need to know the names of the items before runtime, and it doesn't seem to work with a dynamically created form like this.

The only thing I can think of is I need to load the form data into a List< T > and return that to the controller, but I can't think of a way to get C# to allow me to initialize a List< T > and load the values in the view. I know I've got to be missing something, but I'm kinda lost at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing your viewmodel back to your page?  This seems like you are setting the viewmodel with data atleast from a 5000 foot view:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyCallMethod()
{
    FooProperty = getmydatafromsomewhere();

    return View(); 
}
```

Then your page would have a way to build appropriately

```
@model My.Name.Space.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))
{
    @foreach (var item in @Model.FooProperty)
    {
    <div class="FormGroup-items">
        <label asp-for="item.InputType" />
        <input asp-for="item.InputType" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    //other data

    }
}
```

I also assume you have a post setup on the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyCallMethod(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
        //do something with the viewmodel here
        //same page, somewhere else, do something else, etc.
}
```

You can use some tag helpers as well for your labels and inputs if you so chose:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => item.InputType, new { @class="whateverIwant" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.InputType, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Comment: See updated answer.  You should pass the "EmailBuild","Emails" in your form as well.

Comment: Yes.. well, I think I am.. I do have a method with an attribute of [HttpGet] and a second method of the same name with attribute of [HttpPost].  I'm using the Post method in my Form tag.  I think I was using the wrong overload for the @Html.BeginFrom.  I'm going to try using it with your ("action", "controller" ) overload and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Are you passing your viewmodel into your post method?

Comment: my post method is      public IActionResult EmailBuild(EmailBuildViewModel e).  I was just looking at the BeginForm info to figure out how to pass the viewmodel back to the HttpPost method.

Comment: If you post, it should automatically return the viewmodel to the controller you post to so long as it accepts a parameter equivalent to that viewmodel.

Comment: Your suggestion of overload was the trick.. I also found out that I was setting the value of the input item incorrectly.  I was using @html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceModel[x] when it should have been m.ReferenceModel[x].ItemValue 

with those two changes it is now working perfectly!